# Extract urls in text

Tags: php

Let say we've text with more than one url within, so i would like to extract that url and doing some changes then shows up the text.

Here is the code i'm using

```
<?PHP
$text = "This is text with links http://google.com and www.yahoo.com";

$text = ereg_replace( "www\.", "http://www.", $text );
$text = ereg_replace( "http://http://www\.", "http://www.", $text );
$text = ereg_replace( "https://http://www\.", "https://www.", $text );

$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {

$text = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $text);
echo $text;

}else{

echo "NO URLS";

}
?>
```

**The problem**

// output source (repeat for first link)

```
This is text with links <a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">http://google.com</a> and <a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">http://google.com</a>
```

It depends on array so it only takes the first URL `$url[0]` so how can i apply for all links to be found within the text ~ Thanks

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php

Comment: How about adding the global ("g") modifier to your `preg_replace`? `/.../g`

Comment: @rjz AFAIK preg_replace is global by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the next line

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
```

to

```
$reg_exUrl = "/((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?)/";
```

and

```
$text = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $text);
```

to

```
$text = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="\1" rel="nofollow">\1</a>', $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_match_all(...)`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), it returns an array of matches. Then you loop over the result (`$matches`) and replace the found occurences.